# spring tool suite creating runnable jar error finding config file

Tags: java, spring, executable-jar

I am trying to create for the first time a runnable jar within spring tool suite. I use the export feature and create the jar file but when running it, I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.properties (The system cannot find 
the file specified)
```

I have found some suggested solutions here referencing placing the file in the source folder and even though I have done that,it still does not see the file. I even placed it in multiple locations hoping that would work.

[image]

Here I am calling the class to read the file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      System.out.println("GETTING CONFIG PROPERTIES FILE...");
      configuration.readConfig();

....
public static void readConfig() {

    Properties fileProp = new Properties();
    try {

        //OutputStream output = null;
        URL url1 = configuration.class.
                getClassLoader().getResource("config.properties");
        File f = new File(url1.getFile());
        FileReader rd = new FileReader(f.getPath());

        //InputStream infile = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        fileProp.load(rd);
```

EDIT:

Made the change to the file name path by inserting the slash but it seems to not be able to find the file:

```
LOADING CONFIG PROPERTIES FILE...
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.
    JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ccccc.hbasededuper.
    configuration.readConfig(configuration.java:48)
    at com.ccccc.hbasededuper.HBaseMain.main(HBaseMain.java:144)
    ... 5 more
```

That line of code happens to be this:

```
       URL url1 = configuration.class.getClassLoader().
       getResource("/config.properties");

        System.out.println("LOADING CONFIG PROPERTIES FILE...");

        File f = new File(url1.getFile());
        FileReader rd = new FileReader(f.getPath());
```

The error occurs as url1.getFile.

EDIT2:

Figured it out; the problem was the manner in which I was reading the properties file.

```
fileprop.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("config.properties"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the one you want is the one in src/main/resources, and can be referenced via

```
configuration.class.getClassLoader().getResources("/config.properties")
```

Note the '/'.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was when debugging it worked without the  "/" but inserting it for the jar creation worked. Got some other errors to deal with now. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Turned it, it still was not reading file but your suggestion did help debug it.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what made the difference and keeping the config files under
src/main/resources

```
  fileProp.load(configuration.class.
       getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
```